# Can you fix this regex? (German character issue)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

A friend has a German website - all urls need to be redirected to main.php to be processed - unfortunately, any with German characters aren't being redirected.

This is the rule in question:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/ÀÁÅÃÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]+)$ /main.php?qs=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone see an obvious issue?

Cheers!

Comment: `Ä` appears to be missing. Also, no punctuation characters other than `-` and `/` are allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by "german characters", the 6 umlauts and the sharp S? Please give us an example url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an encoding issue and not easy to fix as URLs *should* be UTF-8 encoded but are not required to.

As you want to redirect all URLs and capture the path why not just use this far simpler regular expression?

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /main.php?qs=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @Richard - Do not forget to "accept" an answer if it solves your problem. It will help you to get more answers in the future.

Comment: For some reason it had set a time limit for me before I could accept, thanks to your reminder, I didn't forget!